# How to get last 3 days data in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 1 question on my code. I need to get the latest 3 days data in my database. Below is my code that I have hard code for 1 date. How can I get current date and - 3 days to get the latest 3 days data?

```sql
SELECT a.order_number|| '|' ||a.item_number|| '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.last_data_load, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||b.part_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' || to_char(d.day_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.req_deliv_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||a.currency|| '|' ||a.net_price|| '|' ||a.conf_qty|| '|' ||a.net_price*a.conf_qty|| '|'
FROM bookings_summary a,
     sd_part_dim@dwhprd1.corp.idt.com b,
     sd_customer_dim c,
     time_dim d
WHERE a.part_key = b.part_key
  AND a.ship_to_key = c.customer_key
  AND a.book_date_key = d.day_key
  AND a.order_number||a.item_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT a.order_number||a.item_number
                                        FROM bookings_summary a
                                        WHERE a.last_data_load >= '01-jan-2018');
```

Comment: which db you are using ????'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `current_date` and subtract three days:

```sql
SELECT a.order_number|| '|' ||a.item_number|| '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.last_data_load, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||b.part_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' || to_char(d.day_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.req_deliv_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||a.currency|| '|' ||a.net_price|| '|' ||a.conf_qty|| '|' ||a.net_price*a.conf_qty|| '|'
FROM bookings_summary a
  JOIN sd_part_dim@dwhprd1.corp.idt.com b ON a.part_key = b.part_key
  JOIN sd_customer_dim c ON a.ship_to_key = c.customer_key
  JOIN time_dim d ON a.book_date_key = d.day_key
WHERE (a.order_number, a.item_number) IN (SELECT a.order_number, a.item_number
                                          FROM bookings_summary a
                                          WHERE a.last_data_load >= trunc(current_date) - 3);
```

---

If `(a.order_number, a.item_number)` is unique, you don't even need the sub-select:

```sql
SELECT a.order_number|| '|' ||a.item_number|| '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.last_data_load, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||b.part_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' ||c.customer_num|| '|' || to_char(d.day_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(a.req_deliv_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || '|' ||a.currency|| '|' ||a.net_price|| '|' ||a.conf_qty|| '|' ||a.net_price*a.conf_qty|| '|'
FROM bookings_summary a
  JOIN sd_part_dim@dwhprd1.corp.idt.com b ON a.part_key = b.part_key
  JOIN sd_customer_dim c ON a.ship_to_key = c.customer_key
  JOIN time_dim d ON a.book_date_key = d.day_key
WHERE a.last_data_load >= trunc(current_date) - 3;
```

Note that I re-wrote the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins to an explicit JOIN.

The `IN` clause with concatenation is a really bad idea, because it might actually return wrong results. I changed that to correctly compare the column values without concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

For sql server , you can use :

```
where a.last_data_load >= dateadd(dd,-3,getdate())
```

This function will give you the current date minus 3 days. For other dbs look for `dateadd()` and `getdate()` equivalents

Comment: I have try this previously but I having this issue - "missing right parenthesis" in my sql developer. May I know what I have missing?

Comment: that is some syntax error most probably. attach your exact code and tell us what db you are using if you need more help